# Spring Boot - How to unit test @Service class methods that use @PreAuthorize when using JWT with custom claims

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

We have a Spring Boot backend application that uses JWT authentication implemented using Spring Security with OAuth2 Resource Server. We have secured our web layer by limiting access to URL patterns based on user roles using `antMatchers()` and service layer methods using global method security.

Our JWT tokens are provided by Auth0, where we have configured to include additional user metadata as custom claims. These claims values are verified in `@PreAuthorize` annotations as follows for example:

```
    @PreAuthorize("authentication.principal.claims[@environment.getProperty('jwt.organizationIdClaim')] == @environment.getProperty('current.organizationId')")
    public void deleteUser(String userId) {
```

Here the properties `jwt.organizationIdClaim` and `current.organizationId` are custom properties obtained from the application.properties file.

When I attempt to unit test the above method, I get an exception as follows:

`org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext`

Unit test code:

```
    @Test
    void testDoNotAllowDeletingUsersWithRootRole() {
        auth0ManagementAPIService.deleteUser("auth0|REDACTED");
        assertTrue(true);
    }
```

I tried to run this test using `@WithMockUser`, but this results in the @PreAuthorize expression unable to be evaluated:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'authentication.principal.claims[@environment.getProperty('jwt.organizationIdClaim')] == @environment.getProperty('current.organizationId')'`

Is there any way to add these custom claim data to the `SecurityContext` for these unit tests so that the @PreAuthorize expression evaluates successfully?

We bypassed the JWT requirement in the web layer by using `SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt()`, perhaps there is something similar we could use for @Service class methods?

A sample payload of the JWT that we use appears as follows:

```
{
  "https://dev.api.REDACTED.com/roles": [
    "RESEARCHER",
    "ADMIN",
    "ROOT"
  ],
  "https://dev.api.REDACTED.com/organizationId": "REDACTED",
  "https://dev.api.REDACTED.com/userId": "REDACTED",
  "iss": "https://dev.login.REDACTED.com/",
  "sub": "auth0|REDACTED",
  "aud": [
    "https://dev.api.REDACTED.com",
    "https://REDACTED.us.auth0.com/userinfo"
  ],
  "iat": 1660626647,
  "exp": 1660713047,
  "azp": "REDACTED",
  "scope": "openid profile email offline_access",
  "permissions": [
    ...
  ]
}
```

Here `https://dev.api.REDACTED.com/roles`, `https://dev.api.REDACTED.com/organizationId` and   `https://dev.api.REDACTED.com/userId` are custom claims whose values we need to verify in the @PreAuthorize conditions.

The principal object is of type Jwt and is generated as follows using a custom converter:

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomJwtAuthenticationConverter implements Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {

    private final String rolesClaimName;

    public CustomJwtAuthenticationConverter(String rolesClaimName) {
        this.rolesClaimName = rolesClaimName;
    }

    @Override
    public AbstractAuthenticationToken convert(Jwt jwt) {
        // Get roles claim from the JWT token and add it to a granted authorities list.
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> rolesList = jwt.getClaimAsStringList(rolesClaimName);
        rolesList.forEach(r -> grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r)));
        return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, grantedAuthorities, jwt.getSubject());
    }
}
```

Which is then injected into the security filter chain in the Security config:

```
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(customJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter());
        http
                .cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests(
                        authorize -> authorize
                                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                                .antMatchers("/actuator", "/actuator/health").permitAll()
                                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/users/**").hasAuthority(ROOT_ROLE)
                                .antMatchers("/users/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_ROLE, ROOT_ROLE)
                                .anyRequest().authenticated());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> customJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter() {
        return new CustomJwtAuthenticationConverter(rolesClaimName);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to 'spy' environment bean?

Comment: How do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have exactly what you need there: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons

Sample [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken):

```java
    @Test
    @WithMockJwtAuth(authorities = { "NICE", "AUTHOR" }, claims = @OpenIdClaims(preferredUsername = "Tonton Pirate"))
    void whenGrantedWithNiceRoleThenCanGreet() throws Exception {
        final var actual = mySecuredService.returnSomething();
        //test return falue
    }
```

`@OpenIdClaims` allows you to configure standard OpenID claims (but none is mandatory) and any private claim you like.

The advantage of test annotations over request post-processors is it works without MockMvc (which happens when you want to unit-test secured `@Component` which are not `@Controller`, like `@Service` or `@Repository`). Unfortunately, spring-security team was not interested in it at time I contributed OAuth2 MockMvc post-processors (and WebTestClient mutators). Reason for me starting the lib linked above.

### PS

You might find useful ideas in [other tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials). `resource-server_with_oauthentication` could save you quite some configuration code and `resource-server_with_specialized_oauthentication` could help you improve security expressions readability.

Comment: Looks interesting let me try it out and see. Though I don't understand why something like this wouldn't be supported officially. As in how does the Spring Security team officially expect us to test method level security in this case?

Comment: I never got an answer to this question. This when the idea of OAuth2 test annotation in spring framework was dropped:  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6557#issuecomment-472458228

Comment: What I understood from the given issue page is that they prefer using a JWT request post processor in the controller unit tests. This implies that service class methods are not mocked and are called as is.

Comment: I have been going through the samples. Do I need to configure the resource server using your addons for the unit tests to work? I am trying to limit any third party addons to the test scope if possible.

Comment: No, you don't. Just `@Import(WebSecurityConfig.class)` as done in the dedicated tutorial: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken (@WebMvcTest does not load security config)

Comment: Once you got it working, you really should try `resource-server_with_oauthentication` and `resource-server_with_specialized_oauthentication` tutorials, I'm convinced it is worth the time you'll spend. If you're afraid of using "addons" code, it is composed of just [one configuration](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/webmvc/spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oauth2/config/synchronised/ServletSecurityBeans.java) and one ConfigurationProperties files. Both are open-source => read it

Comment: I tried this: `@WithMockJwtAuth(authorities = {"ROOT"}, claims = @OpenIdClaims(otherClaims = @Claims(stringClaims = @StringClaim(name = "https://dev.api.REDACTED.com/organizationId", value = "e72cc083-6d2c-4f6c-b570-ed32b41a4ccf"))))` on my service class test case but now I get this error: `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oauth2/config/synchronised/ServletSecurityBeans.class]...` Full error omitted due to character limit here.

Comment: I also see that your samples all apply on MockMVC tests and not on service class tests. So could you do a tutorial for how to apply this to service class tests?

Comment: [MessageServiceTests](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/webmvc-jwtauthenticationtoken/src/test/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/samples/webmvc_jwtauthenticationtoken/MessageServiceTests.java)

Comment: You're probably pulling the wrong test lib (you pull spring-addons `SecurityFilterChain` in addition to the one defined in your security-conf). Documented in main README [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons#unit-testing).

Comment: Yeah, I was pulling in `spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-test` when I should have been pulling `spring-addons-oauth2-test`. I tried again and it seems to work in the service class I am testing. I tried one test case with correct claims and one with invalid claims and both cases pass. So, thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. Marking your answer as accepted.